# What does "[5] Killed" mean in ruby

Tags: ruby

We got a response  "[5]   Killed" , any ideas?

We are running a json crawl script and it dies after a few hours with this.

Edit: uses 70% of system memory. written in ruby w/ C++ ruby gems.  It may be dying during a C++ gem.  it dies when loading 2.3GB worth of JSON files into 17.5GB of memory.

Comment: Have you checked messages in `dmesg` or other system logs? If the process was killed by a system due to resources limit, usually there's a message about it there.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, your shell reports that a child process (i.e. your script) was killed (i.e. it received some sort of signal that terminated it - most likely a SIGKILL, but maybe some shell output this message on other signals) due to some circumstances.

It's hard to guess what happened, but if I were you I'd check out system logs (for example, running `dmesg`) - for example, our script might be running out-of-memory and system's OOM killer kills it.

It would really help to diagnose if you'll post more details (i.e. what script, what it does, what is it written in, how much resources does it use, which OS / libraries are used, how exactly do you run it, what's your shell, etc).

Comment: Probably, script exceeds some system limit (like maximum RAM per process, max open files count). Also you should look for memory leaks in your program.